# IFrame on Safari 11 behaving weirldy

Tags: html, iframe, https, safari

In a very similar fashion with a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27605731/iframe-on-safari-failed-to-load-resource), the web application I have creates an iFrame to a login form, with a certain URL and a bunch of GET parameters, but until the said URL is opened in a separate window at least once, the page loaded in the iFrame doesn't seem to be getting the GET parameters at all. This is not a PHP application, however, so there's no `session_start` issue as suggested in the answer to the related question.

I tried tracing the network with Charles, and the only outgoing request I see is a CONNECT request to the domain of the URL without any GET payload.

Not sure if related or important: the main page domain is HTTP, the login form is on HTTPS.

Is there some preflight voodoo that needs to be done for this to work?
The whole solution works as is on Safari 10 and other browsers, IE included.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the `Preferences -> Privacy -> Prevent cross-site tracking` being set to `on`. When switched to `off` works like a charm.